# setBottomSheetCallback is deprecated

Tags: android

while developing an app for object detection using ml kit firebise, i've implemented my bottom sheet but it's not working,so the camera still focused on the object without any result.
code:

```
private void setUpBottomSheet() {
    bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet));
    bottomSheetBehavior.setBottomSheetCallback(
            new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Bottom sheet new state: " + newState);
                    bottomSheetScrimView.setVisibility(
                            newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
                    graphicOverlay.clear();

                    switch (newState) {
                        case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN:
                            workflowModel.setWorkflowState(WorkflowState.DETECTING);
                            break;
                        case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED:
                        case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED:
                        case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HALF_EXPANDED:
                            slidingSheetUpFromHiddenState = false;
                            break;
                        case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_DRAGGING:
                        case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_SETTLING:
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {
                    SearchedObject searchedObject = workflowModel.searchedObject.getValue();
                    if (searchedObject == null || Float.isNaN(slideOffset)) {
                        return;
                    }

                    int collapsedStateHeight =
                            Math.min(bottomSheetBehavior.getPeekHeight(), bottomSheet.getHeight());
                    if (slidingSheetUpFromHiddenState) {
                        RectF thumbnailSrcRect =
                                graphicOverlay.translateRect(searchedObject.getBoundingBox());
                        bottomSheetScrimView.updateWithThumbnailTranslateAndScale(
                                objectThumbnailForBottomSheet,
                                collapsedStateHeight,
                                slideOffset,
                                thumbnailSrcRect);

                    } else {
                        bottomSheetScrimView.updateWithThumbnailTranslate(
                                objectThumbnailForBottomSheet, collapsedStateHeight, slideOffset, bottomSheet);
                    }
                }
            });
```

Error: setBottomSheetCallback is deprecated

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Use `addBottomSheetCallback` and `removeBottomSheetCallback` instead.

Check out the [Android docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/bottomsheet/BottomSheetBehavior#setbottomsheetcallback).

**From the docs:**

> setBottomSheetCallback
>
> This method is deprecated. use
> addBottomSheetCallback(BottomSheetCallback) and
> removeBottomSheetCallback(BottomSheetCallback) instead

Comment: i couldn't understand because where is no idea on how to implement onStateChanged and OnSlide, it should be inside addBottomSheetCallback(BottomSheetCallback) ?

Comment: Yes. Just replace the text setBottomSheetCallback in your code with addBottomSheetCallback.